# Implementing IEnumerable on Custom Collection, and It's Involvement with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable, ienumerator

While this Question seem to be redundant, and every one talk about it, i assure that it's not, or at last about the issue i have, there aren't much of people how talked about this.

So what's the matter?

I want to implement IEnumerable and IEnumerator in my Collection. Well i did this before..., so why i'm still here? i'm here because i'm not sure how Linq Process the data. And what are the best practice on implementing this.

While most of you always point to a sample which the user implement a collection, which it self contain a list or a kind, i did implement a 2 class that i used to parse data, and segment under those data.
each class is very similar to IEnumerable, so yesterday i said, hey it's like enumerator, why don't i bring power of C# keyword, and .... into my classes, with adding IEnumerator and IEnumerable interfaces to it?

So i done doing that. but my class is the one who hold the data, and the cursor, not another collection inside it, and it doesn't say for example:
`myList.GetEnumerator` which return new Enumerator instance, but itself is both enumerator and enumerable, So:

**The Question I Have Is**
does linq use enumerator.reset, and other stuff? does it some how manage to keep data at the place they were? i don't think so myself, but i want to make sure, if i should return a new instance of my class, or just point to `this`.

Here is my current code, which i give it a new instance version of my class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

namespace GabrielWinFormTest.Parsers
{
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public class LineReader:IEnumerator<string>, IEnumerable<string>
    {
        private readonly string _data;
        private int _nextValuePosition;

        //Properties
        object IEnumerator.Current { get { return Current; } }
        public string Current { get; private set; }

        public LineReader(string data)
        {
            _data = data;
            Reset();
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            _nextValuePosition = 1;
            Current = string.Empty;
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            bool result;

            if (_data == null) throw new Exception("Data is null or empty");

            if (_nextValuePosition > Strings.Len(_data))
            {
                result = false; //Return No Data Signature
                Current = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                var nextPos = GetPositionOfLineFeed(_data, _nextValuePosition);
                if (nextPos == 0)
                {
                    result = false; //Returns No Data Signature
                }
                else
                {
                    Current = GetLineAtPosition(_data, nextPos);
                    _nextValuePosition = nextPos + Strings.Len(Current);
                    result = true; //Returns Has Data Signature
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Return Specific Line, Without Moving Cursor (Generate New LineReader Inside Itself)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="position">The position of segment (start by 0)</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string GetLineAt(int position)
        {
            var lineReader = new LineReader(_data);
            var i = 0;
            while (lineReader.MoveNext() && i++ < position)
            {
            }

            return lineReader.Current;
        }

        //Get Position before Next Line (Searching for char(13))
        private int GetPositionOfLineFeed(string str, int lastPosition)
        {
            if (lastPosition == 0) throw new Exception("lastPosition cannot be less than 1");

            int result = 0;
            for (int i = lastPosition; i <= Strings.Len(str); i++)
            {
                if (Strings.Mid(str, i, 1) != Strings.Chr(13).ToString())
                {
                    result = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        //Get non-spaced Value At Given Position
        private string GetLineAtPosition(string str, int position)
        {
            if (position == 0) throw new Exception("position cannot be less than 1");

            string result = string.Empty;
            int i;

            for (i = position; i <= Strings.Len(str); i++)
            {
                if (Strings.Mid(str, i, 1) == Strings.Chr(13).ToString())
                {
                    result = Strings.Mid(str, position, i - position);
                    break;
                }
            }

            //If The value placed at the end of line ( xyz at "??????????????xyz")
            if (i > Strings.Len(str))
                result = Strings.Mid(str, position, i - position);

            return result;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            //Microsoft left it blank in it's sample, so i can do it too :-/
        }

        public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new LineReader(_data);
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

My logic say i'm right, but i want to know the logic of other people behind it.

Comment: i'm sure if i take it there, they will offend me, because the question i asked, itself bring up that this code is not used in production yet, and they only accept working codes, sure this will work, but i'm not sure which is right, maybe you are right, maybe not, last time someone told me your question should be moved there, i got 5 minus rate, for something similar. so i delete the question

Comment: Any LINQ method can use any method the IEnumerable/IEnumerator offers. You have to take care to fulfill that IEnumerable/IEnumerator contract. If you cannot then you should not add that IEnumerable contract to your class.

Comment: well my concern is that contract? i want to know how that will perform? would it manage the cursor for me? or it should always take new instance of enumerator and it cannot operate on an exists data?

Comment: The enumerable is a feature of the Net Library and not Linq.  Linq works just like a foreach loop.  The foreach automatically performs a reset and so does linq.

Comment: Well i know that, since it was on .Net 2 which i start with. What i don't know is how linq, thread the IEnumerator... and how i should implement IEnumerable interface methods, is mine correct? or i should simply pass `this`

Comment: It's usually not a good ideia to implement both IEnumerable and IEnumerator on the same class. Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx, at the end there is a good example.

Comment: So they separate it to not reinitialize the same object again. so if i want to Mix them, i need to reinitialize them. Thank you, i think i got my answer.

Comment: No, you probably should not mix them. Why would you need to mix them anyway? Even if you reinitialize, it will not work correctly in all cases, it might be that the second enumeration initializes before the first one ends.

Comment: Actually, it will work correctly, since you return a new instance on the GetEnumerator method. It is just a strange design that violates the single responsability principle.

Comment: @LucasCorsaletti if i initialize it, it will work with the same exact copy of data as the original one (it can be passed by ref too to decrease this overheat), but with different cursor, so it never cause an issue on the original class of my IEnumerator, toward this special case / class. maybe not work for other, who work with something like object of an Stream.

Comment: What is single response principle, never heard of it, or if i did, in another language meaning does somehow change sometimes. if you mean that a class should do a single job, it still do single job. it's work is to split data, and return them, you may treat it as ienumerable, or as ienumerator,... BTW, i'm not so creative to find new name, it will give me trouble, what this class name should be... and more coupling inside system, which each part of it's is enough complex, due to the API which they write around 2000. for example a list give you both enumerable and enumerator. move to next post

Comment: continue with last msg... also i see things like: for example a list... a list it self is the container of data and it's a enumerable, then it implement an class and return IEnumerator, you don't go to there and initialize the enumerator yourself normally, but my container itself is the enumerator one. and i can simply add an IEnumerable just by adding the interface, and then add return new X(data); to it. maybe still i'm wrong... so i'll look forward to see if you have any other idea

Comment: "it's work is to split data, and return them". The "and" on your phrase shows that it is doing at least two things. I would say it is doing four things: It reads the data, splits the data, is a container for the data as a list, and is also a enumerator. I'm going to post a suggestion on how to split all that as an answer.

Comment: My work time is passed for today, i check tommorow